# is it possible to delay a weblogic deployment of an EJB (ejb-jar) in 5 minutes?

Tags: weblogic

Do anyone knows if it's possible to delay a weblogic deployment of an EJB (ejb-jar) in 5 minutes?

That's because I need to to first make sure to start another service before EJB ready to be called.

Comment: Can you answer my question in your previous post (question) ?

Comment: 1) Can you specify what you meant with "another service"? Is it another EJB? 
2) Are the delayed EJB and the "service" part of the same EAR file? if no, you could set the deployment order. 
3) If the another service is another EJB within the same EAR file, then specify the order with <ejb-relation> element in the weblogic-ejb-jar.xml file. 
4) you can introduce a 5 minute delay in the init method of your EJB with "TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);" part of java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit